# Why is Google's Type A to Type C 2.0 USB cable rated at 3A, when Type A can only support 2.4A?

Tags: usb

Why is Google's Type A to Type C 2.0 USB cable rated at 3A, when Type A can only support 2.4A?

https://store.google.com/product/usb_type_c_to_usb_standard_a_plug_cable?hl=en

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why should a cable's current handling be limited to the maximum that the underlying protocol supports?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Basically, I want my Nexus 6P to charge at maximum speeds (max amperage for USB Type C is 3.0A). I'm trying to understand how this cable can support 3.0 when the Type A connector can only support 2.4A.

Comment: "Charge rate will vary depending on the capabilities of the legacy USB port." - It does support it but the charge rate will depend on the legacy port.  The Amperage was limited by the port not the cable or "capable of up to 3 Amps" how something is worded is important

Comment: It is required to support *at least* 2.4A. It can support as much as the manufacturer makes it support.

Comment: [News posting about USB-C quality variances](http://hardware.slashdot.org/story/15/11/05/1959216/google-engineer-warns-against-perils-of-buying-cheap-third-party-usb-c-cables)

Comment: The implication in the question - as i read it - is that no type-A power source should ever make more than 2.4A available. To do so is to invite an accident - for example if a 2.4A rated cable were ever used in a scenario to supply 3A. Apple on their macbook use a type-c to type-c cable - and this would seem a safer option. In practice just be very selective about what cables you put 3A through. Never buy cheap / off-brand power cables or batteries is a good mantra to live by IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The cable spec is slightly better than the absolute minimum required.

The cable and connectors have to be able to handle the maximum current required.  There is no downside to these items being over-specified other than cost and / or size.

In general, the heavier (larger) the conductors carrying your load current, the lower the losses.  This translates into lower voltage drop in the conductors and therefore may allow better performance of your device.

The other advantage of having larger conductors than the absolute minimum required is that you can have longer cables without running into performance issues.